# Configure .net core logging to log request and response

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, logging, asp.net-core

I'm developing asp .net core 2.1 WEB-API application.

I use ILogger with configuration:

```
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
}
```

And on request i see log:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
>         Executing action method ActivationService.Controllers.ActivationController.Post
>   (ActivationService) with arguments
>   (ActivationService.Contracts.ActivationRequest) - Validation state:
>   Valid

and

> Executed action method
>   ActivationService.Controllers.ActivationController.Post
>   (ActivationService), returned result
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult in 174605.9201ms.

Is there way to confugure asp.net to log with trace ***body*** of response and request?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can implement logging middleware:

```
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            this.next = next;
            logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Request.EnableRewind();

            var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.ContentLength)];
            await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            logger.LogInformation(requestBody);

            var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = responseBody;

                await next(context);

                context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var response = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                logger.LogInformation(response);
                await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then add it to application Builder in Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ....
    app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: 1) in your example i have to change from "context.Request.Body = body;" to "context.Request.Body.Position = 0;", otherwise request came null in controller 2) it's ok, and may be i'll use it. But may be there is  a way to configure standard asp logger to do it?

Comment: @TimurLemeshko, unfortunately, there is no way to configure logger to do that.

Comment: This won't log outgoing calls

Comment: Will not work with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked ` as `Content-Length` header is omitted, so `context.Request.ContentLength` is unavailable. `EnableBuffering` extension is possible workaround. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestrewindextensions.enablebuffering?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: EnableRewind is the method from Internal Asp net namespace and AFAIU it isn't guaranteed that it will work publicly. For instance, I get an error System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http...'
I would suggest to use "EnableBuffering()" which has the same meaning: "Ensure the request Body can be read multiple times."